# How to calculate the semi-axes of an ellipsoid if only the three circumferences are known?

Tags: geometry

I don't know what the "circumferences" are called, they are the red, blue and green lines on the left picture:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6d/Triaxial_Ellipsoid.jpg

If only the lengths of these lines are known, how can I calculate the semi-axes of the ellipsoid? Thanks!

Comment: Seeing how [computing the circumference of just *one* ellipse from its semi-axes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Circumference) already requires the use of an elliptic integral which is a transcendental function, this sounds like a very tricky problem where I wouldn't expect a closed form solution. Numeric optimization should yield good results for most practical applications, though.